# Print Two different Nodes as siblings in 3 Columns

Tags: xslt, bi-publisher

i would like to get Box and Folder Elements as Siblings in 3 columns with Box order.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="BoxFldr.xsl" ?>
    <ListOfBipBoxfldrlbls>
      <Batch>   
        <ListOfFolder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr1</FolderNum>             
            <BoxNumber>Box1</BoxNumber>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr2</FolderNum>       
            <BoxNumber>Box1</BoxNumber>  
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>        
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr3</FolderNum>        
            <BoxNumber>Box1</BoxNumber> 
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr1</FolderNum>
            <BoxNumber>Box2</BoxNumber>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr2</FolderNum>
            <BoxNumber>Box2</BoxNumber>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr3</FolderNum>
            <BoxNumber>Box2</BoxNumber>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr4</FolderNum>
            <BoxNumber>Box2</BoxNumber>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          </ListOfFolder>
        <ListOfBox>
          <Box>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
            <BoxNumber>Box1</BoxNumber>               
          </Box>
          <Box>     
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
            <BoxNumber>Box2</BoxNumber>                
          </Box>
        </ListOfBox>
      </Batch>  
    </ListOfBipBoxfldrlbls>
```

I could Print all the Folders as siblings with the below Code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="ListOfBipBoxfldrlbls/Batch/ListOfFolder | ListOfBipBoxfldrlbls/Batch/ListOfBox" > 
        <xsl:variable name="columns" select="3" />
        <TABLE border="1">
          <xsl:for-each select="Folder[position() mod $columns = 1]"> 
             <TR>
               <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::Folder[position() &lt; $columns]">
                 <TD>
                   <xsl:value-of select="FolderNum" />
                   <xsl:value-of select="BoxNumber" />
                 </TD>
               </xsl:for-each> 
             </TR> 
          </xsl:for-each> 
        </TABLE> 
      </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

### I could get

```
 Box1 Fldr1       Box1 Fldr2     Box1 Fldr3

 Box2 Fldr1       Box2 Fldr2    Box2 Fldr3

 Box2 Fldr4
```

---

but I couldn't get Box and Folders as Siblings.

### Expected Output :

```
 Box1                     Box1 Fldr1       Box1 Fldr2

 Box1 Fldr3              Box2              Box2 Fldr1

 Box2 Fldr2              Box2 Fldr3        Box2 Fldr4
```

---

Can someone Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That doesn't look like XSLT to me.  What language or tool are you actually using?

Comment: Hi I am using BI Publisher and the code I gave is  BI Publisher simplified syntax for xsl. But Direct xsl can also be used in BI Publisher RTF templates. Thanks

Comment: What kind of output do you want to create, plain text or XML or HTML? In the case of XML or HTML, please post the markup you want to create for your sample of input.

Comment: Hi, The Output we want to create is plain text. Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you explain more the logic you've used to get this output?

Comment: Hi added xsl code for Folders as Siblings in 3 Columns.